# passing expressions to curve() within a function

Tags: r

A colleague asked me this, and I have struggled with it.

Suppose I want to define a function that takes an expression (let's say `x^2` for concreteness) as an argument and passes that argument to `curve()`.

If I want to do this the easy way, I just run

```
curve(x^2,from=0,to=3)
```

and it works fine.

Suppose I try to set up a wrapper function (let's say there are other things I want to do inside the wrapper in addition to plotting the curve):

```
f <- function(g) {
    curve(g,from=0,to=3)
}
```

This works if I pass a function:

```
f(function(x) x^2)
```

it fails if I try to pass `x^2`, when R tries to evaluate the expression:

```
f(x^2)
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) (from #2) : object 'x' not found
```

I can try to forestall this by using `substitute` within the function:

```
f0 <- function(g) {
    str(substitute(g))
    curve(substitute(g),from=0,to=3)
}
f0(x^2)
## language x^2
## Error in curve(substitute(g), from = 0, to = 3) (from #3) : 
##  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

OK, that suggests maybe I should try

```
f <- function(g) {
    h <- as.expression(substitute(g))
    str(h)
    curve(as.expression(substitute(g)),from=0,to=3)
}
f(x^2)
##  expression(x^2)
## Error in curve(as.expression(substitute(g)), from = 0, to = 3) (from #4) : 
##  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

For what it's worth,

- this fails differently with `curve(h,...)` ("function `h` not found")
- it fails in the same way if `as.call()` is substituted for `as.expression()`
- `curve()` doesn't work on expressions in any case:

```
curve(expression(x^2),from=0,to=1)
## Error in curve(expression(x^2), from = 0, to = 1) : 
##   'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

If I try debugging `curve()` to see what's happening, we have:

```
sexpr <- substitute(expr)
...
if (!((is.call(sexpr) || is.expression(sexpr)) && xname %in% 
    all.vars(sexpr))) 
    stop(...)
```

Here `sexpr` is `substitute(g)`, which fails the `xname %in% all.vars(sexpr)` test ...

Any ideas about how to handle this?

Comment: Did you give `do.call` a shot?  It seems like it might work like it does with `lm`, `glm`, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't mean to ask-and-then-answer, but I figured out the (an?) answer with a little bit more poking around -- it occurred to me that I hadn't tried `eval` yet.  `eval(curve(substitute(g),from=0,to=3))` does *not* work, but this does:

```
f1 <- function(g) {
     eval(substitute(curve(g,from=0,to=3)))
}
f1(x^2)
```

**update**: @RichardScriven suggests that `do.call()` might work too -- and it does!

```
f2 <- function(g) {
    do.call(curve,list(substitute(g),from=0,to=3))
}
f2(x^2)
```

Further explication is welcome!

Comment: it looks like this functionality was only ever meant to work interactively (top-level), so the workarounds need to construct the exact same call as you'd write interactively, _then_ evaluate.

Comment: Well, at least you didn't suggest `eval(parse(...))` tho' you came perilously close :-) .  I agree w/ Richard S.  that `do.call` is your best friend in cases like this.